# Polymorphism - how to check if a superclass is a subclass?

Tags: java, polymorphism

This is my code:

```
public class WriteReviewController {
    
    private OverviewActivity overviewActivity;
    private WriteReviewActivity writeReviewActivity;
    ...
    
    public WriteReviewController(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
                if (appCompatActivity.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OverviewActivity.class))
                    this.overviewActivity = (OverviewActivity) appCompatActivity;
                else if (appCompatActivity.getClass().isAssignableFrom(WriteReviewActivity.class))
                    this.writeReviewActivity = (WriteReviewActivity) appCompatActivity;
            }
    }
```

This is a controller for my application. I would like this to check whether the parameter `appCompatActivity` is an `OverviewActivity` or a `WriteReviewActivity`. This method would be invoked for these two activities just passing as parameter `this`.

Is this check correct or should I use `instaceof` instead of `isAssignableFrom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `instanceof` most of the cases, it is unnecessary to invoke `isAssignableFrom` manually. That should be done if you handle `Class` objects, but here you have the instances themselves.

So using `instanceof` your code will look the following:

```java
public class WriteReviewController {

    private OverviewActivity overviewActivity;
    private WriteReviewActivity writeReviewActivity;
    //...

    public WriteReviewController(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        if (appCompatActivity instanceof OverviewActivity)
            this.overviewActivity = (OverviewActivity) appCompatActivity;
        else if (appCompatActivity instanceof WriteReviewActivity)
            this.writeReviewActivity = (WriteReviewActivity) appCompatActivity;
        }
    }
}
```

The more clean code would be to write two constructors instead:

```java
public class WriteReviewController {

    private OverviewActivity overviewActivity;
    private WriteReviewActivity writeReviewActivity;
    //...

    public WriteReviewController(OverviewActivity overviewActivity) {
        this.overviewActivity = overviewActivity;
    }

    public WriteReviewController(WriteReviewActivity writeReviewActivity) {
        this.writeReviewActivity = writeReviewActivity;
    }
}
```

But you should do that only if this is the only 2 ways you want to instantiate `WriteReviewController`. Your code allows passing an `AppCompatActivity` which is neither `OverviewActivity` nor `WriteReviewActivity`, so the behavior is not the same, I just mention this.

Comment: This is a very clear answer. A doubt: "But you should do that only if this is the only 2 ways you want to instantiate WriteReviewController." but I can simply add others n costructors... can't I?

Comment: Another doubt: should listeners be implemented in a controller's logic or in a view? What I did is is a controller's logic: views simply initialize view components due to findViewById and then initialize WriteReviewController initializing it and then recalling setListenerOnSpecificView. If I haven't been clear, I can edit the post

Comment: @ItsGhost you should rather write all your logic in the controller instead of the view. Most likely any model you use, the view part is only for visualization, so its values are getting modified from outside directly or though binding. In my opinion view must contain logic only for visualization, like calculation of a color value etc...

Comment: Then my solutions is correct... view only shows visualization, setting a controller for the logic

Comment: @ItsGhost You can add more constructors yes, but if you keep your original constructor and also the two for `OverviewActivity` and `WriteReviewActivity`, then it - however it will compile and function, but - will be a bit ambiguous. Having an `OverviewActivity`, you could call 2 constructors, one expecting an `AppCompatActivity` and one expecting an `OverviewActivity`. But that all is based on what you really pass to the constructor actually. If only either `OverviewActivity` or `WriteReviewActivity`, then replacing the one with the two construcors is better, otherwise keep the one you have.